# RENDER_RESPONSE takes to long in seam

Tags: rendering, richfaces, seam, long-integer, phase

I write application using JBOSS Seam with Richfaces. Unfortunately some pages of it load very long especially when I want to show about 100 rows (or more) in table .
Getting response from database takes about 2453 ms, so it is quite well. However the phase RENDER_RESPONSE takes about 23750 ms, so it is unacceptable. The object which i return has no EAGER connections.

Hope that somebody can help me or give some hint what else can I do to find problem.

Greetings, 
Fryta 
PS. Here you have log from my application: 
09:49:52,125 INFO  [[/my_aplication]] BEFORE - INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 - / 
my_aplication/Report.seam
09:49:54,578 INFO  [Report] End generating report: 2453
09:49:54,578 INFO  [[/my_aplication]] AFTER  - INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 - / 
my_aplication/Report.seam
09:49:54,578 INFO  [[/my_aplication]] BEFORE - RENDER_RESPONSE 6 - / 
my_aplication/Report.seam
09:49:54,687 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594687
09:49:54,687 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594687
09:49:54,687 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594687
09:49:54,687 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594687
09:49:54,687 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594687
09:49:54,718 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314594718
09:50:18,437 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314618437
09:50:18,437 INFO  [Report] getResultList(): 1285314618437
09:50:18,468 INFO  [[/my_aplication]] AFTER  - RENDER_RESPONSE 6 - / 
my_aplication/Report.seam
09:50:18,890 INFO  [TimingFilter]

09:50:18,890 INFO  [TimingFilter] Total: 18258ms dla: /my_aplication/ 
Report.seam

Answer (score 1):

I see this line in your log:

```
getResultList(): 1285314594687
```

...repeated quite a lot.  What does this call do?  Does it just return a List that was initialized elsewhere?  Or is it making a call to the database?  If there is any sort of logic involved in the call, that could be where your slowdown is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this very great post on [how you can speed up your JSF/Seam/Richfaces](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/speed_up_your_jsf_app_1.html) application written by [Dan Allen](http://www.mojavelinux.com/about/biography.php) (which is the author of Seam in Action)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it occurs because you are lazy-loading associated entities. Because Seam has built-in support for Open Session in View pattern (which avoids LazyLoadingException), **For each lazy associated entity, Hibernate hits the database** You can override getResultList (or create your custom method) and *load all of needed entities by using a single SQL query*